# Search in file for number, increment and replace

Tags: tcl

I have a VHDL file which has a line like this:

```
constant version_nr     :integer := 47;
```

I want to increment the number in this line in the file. Is there a way to accomplish this with TCL?

Comment: You can do this in many ways in most if not all programming languages, and Tcl is certainly no exception. Are you having some concrete problem doing this that we can help you with?

Answer (score 2):

This is principally a string operation. The tricky bit is finding the line to operate on and picking the number out of it. This can be occasionally awkward, but it is mainly a matter of choosing a suitable regular expression (as this is the kind of parsing task that they excel at). A raw RE to do the matching would be this:

```
^\s*constant\s+version_nr\s*:integer\s*:=\s*\d+\s*;\s*$
```

This is essentially converting all possible places for a whitespace sequence into `\s*` (except where whitespace is mandatory, which becomes `\s+`) and matching the number with `\d+`, i.e., a digit sequence. We then add in parentheses to *capture* the interesting substrings, which are the prefix, the number, and the suffix:

```
^(\s*constant\s+version_nr\s*:integer\s*:=\s*)(\d+)(\s*;\s*)$
```

Now we have enough to make the *line* transform (which we'll do as a procedure so we can give it a nice name):

```
proc lineTransform {line} {
    set RE {^(\s*constant\s+version_nr\s*:integer\s*:=\s*)(\d+)(\s*;\s*)$}
    if {[regexp $RE $line -> prefix number suffix]} {
        # If we match, we increment the number...
        incr number
        # And reconcatenate it with the prefix and suffix to make the new line
        set line $prefix$number$suffix
    }
    return $line
}
```

In Tcl 8.7 (which you won't be using yet) you can write this as this more succinct form:

```
proc lineTransform {line} {
    # Yes, this version can be a single (long) line if you want
    set RE {^(\s*constant\s+version_nr\s*:integer\s*:=\s*)(\d+)(\s*;\s*)$}
    regsub -command $RE $line {apply {{- prefix number suffix} {
        # Apply the increment when the RE matches and build the resulting line
        string cat $prefix [incr number] $suffix
    }}}
}
```

Now that we have a line transform, we've just got to apply that to all the lines of the file. This is easily done with a file that fits in memory (up to a few hundred MB) but requires additional measures for larger files as you need to stream from one file to another:

```
proc transformSmallFile {filename} {
    # Read data into memory first
    set f [open $filename]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f

    # Then write it back out, applying the transform as we go
    set f [open $filename w]
    foreach line [split $data "\n"] {
        puts $f [transformLine $line]
    }
    close $f
}

proc transformLargeFile {filename} {
    set fin [open $filename]
    # The [file tempfile] command makes working with temporary files easier
    set fout [file tempfile tmp [file normalize $filename]]

    # A streaming transform; requires that input and output files be different
    while {[gets $fin line] >= 0} {
        puts $fout [transformLine $line]
    }

    # Close both channels; flushes everything to disk too
    close $fin
    close $fout

    # Rename our temporary over the original input file, replacing it
    file rename $tmp $filename
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such an extensive answer. I will try this approach. In the meantime I found an ugly shortcut. The file is a short package file which is static except for the number so I split it into three files, one which hold the contents before the number, the number itself and one that hold the contents after the number. I then just open the files, increment the number and append the strings into a new file.